# Get ssh connection to an openshift pod

Tags: kubernetes, ssh, openshift, kubernetes-pod, openssh

I need to remote debug my c++ based application running on an openshift cluster using visual studio.
For this reason, I need a working ssh connection to my pod.
I am using **CRC cluster**

Here is what I have tried so far.
I installed openssh-server on the pod through docker file.
Then I accessed the pod's shell, started the server and generated the keys.
Then I tried to connect to the server locally through the pod's shell.

```
ssh -vvv -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@localhost
```

I get the following log

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/root/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup localhost:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IPV6_TCLASS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'root'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /root/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by ::1 port 22
```

I have tried the same with **minikube cluster** where I can successfully connect locally to the ssh server.

Answer (score 0):

While I'll admit I haven't tried it, installing SSH on OpenShift almost certainly isn't going to work out of the box because the default container permissions likely won't enough. (In comparison, minikube is designed for developers and thus is very insecure by default.) The most notable issue being that you can't run containers as root by default, although their may be other issues as well. While I could talk you through the steps to run a OpenShift pod in an unsafe privileged mode, this seems like an extremely hard way to try and debug a pod.

I know you said that you "need to debug in Visual Studio and thus need SSH", but wouldn't any terminal into your pod work? Have you tried `oc rsh`? Or just opening a terminal through the OpenShift UI?

The whole "how to debug a pod" chapter of the docs might be helpful: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/support/troubleshooting/investigating-pod-issues.html